# error: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to get the top of my footer.but i am getting this error: Cannot read property 'top' of null

here is my html

```
<footer class="footer" role="complementary" id="myfooter">

</footer>
```

and in jquery

```
var topoffooter=$('#myfooter').offset().top;
```

can anybody help regarding this

Comment: Where do you have this script placed?

Comment: $('#myfooter').offset() will be null in your case, check if it is not null then get top property.

Comment: The code works perfectly, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCj2S/)

Comment: load script at the bottom of the page or wrap it inside `$(document).ready()`. Nothing wrong with the code you posted, just the ordering is probably incorrect.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/66RWt/

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEM**

The problem might be happening because your script is not able to find the DOM element.
The element should be there in the DOM before it is used by javaScript

---

**DEBUGGING**

Instead of this line `var topoffooter=$('#myfooter').offset().top;` just try to alert the length of jQuery object

```
alert($('#myfooter').length);
```

It must be greater than zero to work, and if not we are on the right path to solve the issue.

---

**SOLUTION**

1) You can put the scripts just before the closing of body tag - `</body>` - *PREFERRED*

2) Or, execute your scripts on document(DOM) ready event using jQuery's
`$(document).ready()` http://api.jquery.com/ready/