# jQuery Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to make a DIV fall when a piece of text is hovered upon. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/4/) is the original effect and this:

```
var $dropDiv = $('#dropDiv');
$('#holder p').on('hover', function () {
    // Get position of clicked div
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    // Get dimensions of said div
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    var w = $(this).outerWidth();

    // Get dimensions of dropping div
    var dh = $dropDiv.outerHeight();
    var dw = $dropDiv.outerWidth();

    // Determine middle position
    var initLeft = offset.left + ((w / 2) - (dw / 2));

    // Animate drop
    $dropDiv.css({
        left: initLeft,
        top: $(window).scrollTop() - dh,
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'block'
    }).animate({
        left: initLeft,
        top: offset.top - dh,
        opacity: 1
    }, 800, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

is my code. At first I thought it was a problem with my libraries, so I switched to the versions the fiddle has.

```
<script src="fall.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The fiddle also had some CSS so I matched up to it

```
#holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;   
}
#dropDiv {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    background: #ccc; 
}
```

I even checked the error console and there are no errors, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I am using Safari Version 5.1.10 and expect it to work for me and Chrome users at least.

Comment: can you give a fiddle of *your attempt*...that might show something??

Comment: `JQuery` should be loaded at first

Comment: it's working fine?what the exact issue is?if you want to make a DIV fall when a piece of text is hovered upon. then just change click to hover $('#holder a').on('hover', function()

Comment: @priyajain its not working fine for him in his project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you include your code ? I had similar problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      YOUR HTML CODE
     <script type="text/javascript"> your code</script>
     or
     <script src="fall.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Include your jQuery code after the html code. bottom in  tag
that should work

also put your code inside ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    your code here...
})
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be the order.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="fall.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

try wrapping the code inside -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //code here

});
```

It is possible that your javascript is not getting executed to to the problem of the same being run prior to the elements being loaded to the DOM

+

If your specified javascript is inside fall.js, since it uses jquery load the fall.js file after jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take 2 Steps -

1) **ORDERING** - The js file/code using jquery lib. functions should always come jquery file is included

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="fall.js"></script>
```

2) **ELEMENT SHOULD BE AVAILABLE IN DOM** - Either the js/script should be the last thing in the body or use jquery dom ready event
([**More Detail Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947682/error-cannot-read-property-top-of-null/20947856#20947856))

Answer (score -1):

I can spot a little Javascript vs. CSS confusion here.

```
$('#holder p').on( 'mouseover', function() {
    // code
});
```

Comment: Damn, whoever down voted my answer is right, I always forget jQuery knows the `hover` shorthand. m(

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$(function(){
   //you code here
})
```